# How to get the updated datagrid after removing the filter for datagrid in c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview with 5 columns and each column has a dropdown so that user can filter the data for each column. 
I also have "Clear Filetr" link, where user can remove the filter after sorting.
Whenever I am make some changes in the datagridview, then if i apply Clear filter, the original datagridview is displayed and the changes are not updated.
How can I get the updated Datagridview after clicking on "Clear Filter"

I have used

```
"Datagridview.RefreshEdit()";
```

But I am not getting exact result.

Comment: Please specify wether you mean a [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) as you said in the text or a [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) as you have linked in the Tags

Comment: its Datagridview

Comment: Use the BindingSource.Filter property to filter your dgv.

Answer (score 0):

one way to solve this problem is to write a method where you set all the values of your datagrid to the starting data. After clicking the "Clear Filter" your grid should be fine!